# different sources for onTextChanged

Tags: javascript, text, textfield, qml

I have a TextField which text could be edited by human or by a function on my program. There's a way to recognize which is the source?

Now I'm using "onTextChanged", but I need to separate human input from other inputs.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let your text element has this id :

`id: fooText`

Then you can do something like this :

```
property bool functionEdit : false

function setText(newText)
{
   functionEdit = true 
   fooText.text = newText
}

onTextChanged:
{
   if( true == functionEdit )
   {
          console.log ( "Text changed from function" )
          functionEdit = false
   }

   else
   {
          console.log ( "Text changed by Human being" )
   }       
}
```